# FileNotFoundError message not printing

Tags: python-3.x, file, exception, filenotfoundexception, try-except

The message in FileNotFoundError does not print, it works fine for the ValueError, below is the code to implement this:

```
    try:
        with open(path) as f:
            if header==True:
                next(f)
            for line in f:    
                try:
                    cnt += 1
                    a = line.count("|") + 1
                    if a == fields:
                        b.append(line)
                        yield b  
                    else:
                        #raise ValueError(f"'{tail}' has {a} fields on line {cnt} but expected {fields}")
                        raise ValueError("Hello")
                except ValueError as v:
                    print(v)
                    continue
        
        raise FileNotFoundError("Wrong file or file path")
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        print(e)
```

The output below prints the Value error message but not the FileNotFoundError:

FileNotFoundError:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C://Users/Documents/abcde.txt'
```

ValueError:

```
['bob|1|23\n']
Hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileNotFoundError` exception is raised in the statement `with open(path) as f:`. The control is immediately passed to the `except FileNotFoundError as e:` part, which prints the exception. Your code `raise FileNotFoundError("Wrong file or file path")` is not executed.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, is there a way to correct this, unlike the ValueError there is no else statement here to add the raise Exception

Comment: Why do you want to raise that exception by hand at all if it is already raised by the `with` statement?